# Реализация boost::any

Tags: c++, boost

Необходимо сделать базовую реализацию `boost::any`.
Главное условие: чтобы можно было свободно хранить в контейнерах разные типы. 
Требуется такое поведение:

```
MyAny a = 5;
cout << a.get() << endl; // a.get() -> int
a = "sdfsdf"; // Нельзя!!!

std::vector<MyAny> vec;
MyAny b = 5;
MyAny c = "sdfsdf";
MyAny d = MyClass(1, 4);
vec.push_back(b);
vec.push_back(c);
vec.push_back(d);
```

Подскажите, где посмотреть как реализовать подобный функционал.

Comment: `boost::any` использует шаблон проектирования *Type Erasure* (стирание типа). Пример кода можно посмотреть в статье «[Идиомы С++. Type erasure](https://habrahabr.ru/post/207294/)» на Хабрахабре.

Comment: Технически, `MyAny a = 5; cout << a.get() << endl; // a.get() -> int` реализовать нельзя, т.к. тип возвращаемого get значения неопределён.. Однако можно возвращать proxy-объект, для которого будет перегружен `operator <<`, который будет в зависимости от типа либо выводить значение в поток, либо бросать исключение. Можно сделать проще, и перегрузить `operator <<` для самого any. Или же можно сделать get шаблонным, и бросать исключение в случае  несоответствия типов.

Comment: @ВикторСирнов, да, но учитывая, что тип изменять не будет у экземпляра, тип возвращаемого значения get() известем в момент инициализации, вопрос как скрыть шаблон чтобы можно было использовать контейнеры

Answer (score 4):

Если в двух словах, то идея такая. `Any` будет хранить в себе указатель на объект, который хранит в себе то, что вы хотите положить в `Any`. Чтобы безопасно извлекать данные будет использоваться понижающее приведение типа `dynamic_cast`.

Для начала опишем небольшую иерархию "хранителей" данных:

```
class IValue{
public:
    virtual ~IValue(){}
};

template<class T>
class Value : public IValue{
    T _value;
public:
    explicit Value(const T &value):
        _value(value)
    {}
    const T& get() const{
        return _value;        
    }
};
```

Тут все просто. Базовый класс `IValue`, от него наследуется шаблон `Value`, в котором можно хранить объект любого типа(кроме тех, которые не поддерживают операцию копирования).

Теперь как будет выглядеть минималистичная реализация `Any`:

```
class Any{
    std::unique_ptr<IValue> _value;
public:
    template<class T>
    Any(const T &value):
        _value(new Value<T>(value))
    {}

    template<class T>    
    T get() const{
        Value<T> *value = dynamic_cast<Value<T>*>(_value.get());
        if(!value){
            return T ();
        }

        return value->get();
    }
};
```

`Any` хранит указатель типа `IValue`. Когда мы пытаемся прочитать записанные данные, выполняется понижающее приведение типа:

```
Value<T> *value = dynamic_cast<Value<T>*>(_value.get());
```

Если `dynamic_cast` вернет `0`, значит мы пытаемся извлечь неправильный тип.

Вам, для ваших целей, нужно еще реализовать копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания, в которых будет выполняться глубокое копирование.

[Полный пример](http://cpp.sh/3ihb7)

**PS:** Кстати, в `a = "sdfsdf";` нет ничего криминального. По-моему, куда более естественно выглядит реализация в которой так делать можно. Вам придется приложить дополнительные усилия, чтоб реализовать такое ограничение.

Comment: @Abyx, а какая альтернатива?

Comment: @Abyx, `QVariant`, кстати, [возвращает `T()`](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h#L569) и прекрасно себя чувствует.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, исключение. Дизайн Qt приводить в пример не стоит, он точно не является примером для подражания.

Comment: @ixSci, а на мой взгляд исключение это плохая идея. Излишнее усложнение кода, утечки памяти, `std::terminate` и  неопределенное поведение стандартных алгоритмов. ИМХО, уж лучше вернуть `T()` и добавить метод `canConvert` или вроде того.

Comment: Все бы ничего, но суть не в динамическом типе `a = 5; a = "dsff";` а в том чтобы я один раз создал перменую и она всего хранила один типо, НО тип определился во время инициализации (не `auto`), и чтобы этот тип можно было положить в контейнер `vector<Any> a{Any(5), Any("6")};` и пройдясь по нему получить эти дынные `for(Any &x : a){ cout << x.get() << endl; x = foo(x.get()); } // foo() Полиморфная функция для int и string`

Comment: @shotInLeg это невозможно, так как `x.get()` возвращает фиксированный тип. А отнаследовать int и string от чего-то ещё не получится